# Criar um processo autônomo em uma aplicação web

Tags: php, aplicação-web, microsserviços

Tenho um sistema web com uma arquitetura mvc, ele simplesmente carrega informações de um banco e exibe na tela. Preciso criar duas funcionalidades que rodem independentemente de um usurário estar acessando a pagina.

Ex: Preciso carregar um arquivo .csv e passar ele para o banco, mas o arquivo é meio pesado (cerca de 200mb), atualmente passo o arquivo por ajax para uma classe php e recebo a resposta quando ele terminou de ser carregado no banco, isso trava muito a visualização do cliente, gostaria de enviar o arquivo e acompanhar em outra tela o progresso do carregamento.

Esse é um exemplo, tenho algumas outras tarefas que demoram um certo tempo, de forma geral queria apenas executa-las e fazer com que elas rodem sozinhas no servidor.

Não tenho muito conhecimento em aplicações web li um pouco a respeito de dividir estas tarefas em micro serviços, mas não sei exatamente se essa é a solução do problema.

Comment: Poste como você importa os dados para o banco, é provável que a forma que isso é feito possa ser otimizada

Comment: Tem várias técnicas diferentes nos links de fechamento acima. Caso nada resolva, queira [edit] sua postagem dando mais detalhes da necessidade específica.

Answer (score 0):

se o seu servidor é linux(provavelmente) você pode resolver isso usando o cron job. procure no google por `crontab` ou via command line `man crontab` , basicamente você deverá criar um script php e rodar via cli `php nomedoarquivo.php`

Comment: aqui teria um exemplo em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358382/execute-php-script-in-cron-job